# Textures blink where there would be black

Tags: textures, unreal-4

[image: Bug]

I am texturing my level, but *every* single texture "blinks" where there would be black, (as seen in photo) I dont know how to fix this, they worked fine earlier.

Comment: I don't know anything about UE4, but "blinking" is often cause by depth fighting: two planes are exactly at the same spot so they 'fight' to be displayed. Make sure you only have one geometry there.

Comment: Tried that but still not working..

Comment: People may help you better if you give more details.